# Goldstein conservation of Hamiltonian example problem

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, conservation-laws

In *Goldstein's Classical Mechanis* section 8.2 (page 345 in the third edition) there is as example that should illustrate how the Hamiltonian can be conserved without energy being conserved. It goes like this:

> Suppose a point mass $m$ is attached to a spring, of force constant $k$, the other end of which is fixed on a massless cart that is being moved uniformly by an external device with speed $v_0$ if we take as the general coordinate the position $x$  then the Lagrangian of the system is obviously $$L=\frac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}-\frac{k}{2}(x-v_0t)^2.$$

Why is this true?

if the coordinate is given by $x-v_0t$ then ''$\dot{x}$'' should be $\dot{x}-v_0$ but that would mean that the Lagrangian would be

$$L=\frac{m(\dot{x}-v_0)^2}{2}-\frac{k}{2}(x-v_0t)^2=L=\frac{m(\dot{x}^2-2\dot{x}v_0+v_0^2)}{2}-\frac{k}{2}(x-v_0t)^2,$$

which is obviously not the same as the above Lagrangian.

What is wrong with this picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kinetic energy is related to the speed of the particle in a fixed frame, not relative to the cart. $x(t)$ is the position of the particle with respect to a fixed axis, so its speed is $\dot x$. $(x-v_0 t)$ appears in the potential energy because the extension of the spring is the position of the particle with respect to the cart.